# Find the missing piece (edit)

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

[image: 4][image: 5][image: 6]

I guess that these questions may use different logic independently or not i don't know. I just found one logic that fits only to the first one.

*These questions are from the one of high IQ Society founded by Xavier Jouve Ph.D for the top 0.3% of people along the IQ spectrum.

edit:[other questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjCP9.png) , [last simillar type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evKQc.jpg)

Comment: does XJ explain the pattern of the boxes as a prelude to these type of puzzles anywhere?

Comment: No, these were totally new types. No additional information were given before.

Comment: Ah, so they ARE separate puzzles rather than 3 pieces of one; thanks for the update. I don't know how much of a difference that makes but I feel like the logic between each can vary much more than if they were linked. Now, were 45-48 also the same type of puzzle? IE further examples of those above?

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjCP9.png) this is other questions, [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evKQc.jpg)  this one  only seems simillar type that left. sorry for my previously not mentioned about this.

Comment: As you took this test, did you find that the previous questions, starting from 1, helped you develop a progressive understanding of the structure for the following problems? That is, by completing questions 1-10 in order, did you find you had a better understanding of the structure and what they were looking for in questions 11-20? In the end I guess I'm asking if you have a link to the test you took so that we may investigate to gain further insight into the specific questions you are asking about.

Comment: Also, in case it hasn't been said yet, welcome to Puzzling.SE! You can gain another badge by checking out https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thank you for your answer and kindness, this test is JCTI [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2W6Y.jpg) which now closed, so i tested it with App here which backed up that test. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.afgArtist.iqtestgeniusivspatialtest  (i'm using iphone so i ran that app with the BlueStack program.

Answer (score 1):

I always found these kind of puzzles silly. There are an infinite number of justifications one could make -- and what you're really trying to do is predict the kind of justification a test-maker would deem sufficiently intelligent-sounding so as to warrant consideration.

That being said, here are my thoughts:

Puzzle 1

> Answer 2.  All blocks have to have at least one pair.  A pair can either mean two white pieces adjacent to each other and in the same direction, or a single black piece anywhere in the same direction. We can rule out 1, 5, and 6 because they either don't have adjacent white pieces, or they have more than one black piece.

Puzzle 2

> Answer 3. Pretty straightforward.  You need a black block in every possible horizontal configuration to make a grouping of 'four.'

Puzzle 3

> Answer 6. It's hard for me to fathom why any combination of pattern ideas would yield a completely distinct block from one already present. 
>  The most obvious answer would be half black (on top) and half white.  Given that such a block is not present, perhaps the answer is as silly as "pick a block already present in the above diagram."

Edit: Fixed spoiler

Answer (score 0):

This is speculation but...
I got a little complicated answer for the first puzzle. Anyway here it goes:

> It could be 5 because,
>  A) From the first two pairs of squares to the one next to it there is this transition (in order):
>  
>  1) Completely overlap the two squares to make a single square
>  2) Turn the new square 90 degrees clockwise
>  3) Turn all black rectangles into white rectangles and vice versa
>  
> B) Then from the one square to the other two next to it
>  
>  1) The top black rectangles goes up one step and the bottom black goes down one step.
>  2) Turn the square 90 degrees anti-clockwise
>  Multiply the newly formed square by 2
>  
>  Then repeat the steps A and B for the next two transitions (from the two in 
>  B to the answer and the answer to the last two squares) and the answer 5
>  will fit the bill to accommodate this pattern.

The second one:

> I think the answer is 2. From section one to two it is the black rectangle in the bottom square in section one moves up one place to generate the square in the next section. Repeat this for section 3 to 4. 
>  The transition between section 2 and 3 is due to the complete overlap of the squares from the previous section and then multiplying the resulting square by two. Repeat this for section 4 to 5.

The last one:

> The last one might be 6 because of this:
>  From section 1 to section 2:
>  imagine a square in the second section split in two along the x axis in the 
>  middle. Now you put the whole colour of the bottom square in the first 
>  section into the top half and the top right colour into the bottom half.
>  This will form the square of the second section.
>  Repeat this for the transition between section 3 and 4 to form square 4.
>  
>  From Section 2 to 3:
>  
>  Duplicate the square at two and rotate one of it as 180 degrees the one you 
>  rotate 180 degrees results in the top square and the one unaltered leads to 
>  the bottom square in 3.
>  Repeat this process to go from section 4 to 5.

Comment: Can you please hide your solutions with spoiler tags? :)

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: I proposed an edit to your answer with tags added. There is a guide on spoiler syntax [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup) (see the accepted answer) which you may find useful.